# How to operate on batches with high efficiency in redis cluster?

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster

I have a map data to cache in redis cluster, such as:

```
{
    "demoKey:{1}":{"key1":"value1"},
    "demoKey:{2}":{"key2":"value2"},
    "demoKey:{3}":{"key3":"value3"}
}
```

If using `lua script`, I get RedisCommandExecutionException with accessing a non local key in a cluster node.

I know there is a way to tag `{demokey}` to avoid the RedisCommandExecutionException with accessing a non local key, but it leads to all data cache in the same slot, is it a good way?

I can also use `RedisTemplate` instance to cache data iteratively, but is it with high efficiency?

Appreciating for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the answer of your questions depend on the application and use-cases.

> ... it leads to all data cache in the same slot, is it a good way?

If the number of data with same hashtag is small, say not more than a hundred, it should be fine.

But if the number is large, say hundreds of thousands or even more, it is unlikely to be a good idea. In that case,

> ... to cache data iteratively

is the option you may have to go for.

Comment: If the number is large,  would there lead to a performance problem, such as too many redis connection?

Comment: "too many redis connection" - unlikely. "performance problem" - one of the cluster nodes could become data hotspot.